# Andoid открытие DialogFragment при нажатии элемента RecyclerView и передача объекта

Tags: java, android

Имеется код

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvShopName;
        public TextView tvChainStores;
        public TextView tvShopAddress;
        public TextView tvShopModeWork;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvShopName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopName);
            tvChainStores = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChainStores);
            tvShopAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopAddress);
            tvShopModeWork = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewShopModeWork);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Shop shop = shops.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    DialogFragmentShopsParameters dialogFragmentShopsParameters = new DialogFragmentShopsParameters();
                    dialogFragmentShopsParameters.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Хочу чтобы при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView, открылось диалоговое окно, и передать туда параметр.

Но никак не могу получить getSupportFragmentManager. Понимаю, что  это из-за адаптера, но не знаю как решить

Answer (score 3):

Передавайте в адаптер контекст и сохраняйте его:

```
this.context=context;
```

Вызывайте в `onClick`:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
      Shop shop = shops.get(getAdapterPosition());
      DialogFragmentShopsParameters dialogFragmentShopsParameters =
           DialogFragmentShopsParameters.newInstance(shop.getId());
      dialogFragmentShopsParameters
          .show(((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager(),"dialog");
 }
```

Параметры лучше передавать через конструкцию `newInstance();`

```
 public static DialogCustom newInstance(int id) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ID, id);
        DialogCustom fragment = new DialogCustom();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
 }
```

Доставать:

```
getArguments().getInt(ID);
```

Comment: не сможете эту конструкцию в качестве примера привести

Comment: @danilshik, добавил

Comment: а object как передать?

Comment: имплементируйте вашему `object` `Serializable` и делайте `args.putSerializable(OBJECT, obj)`;